# How do I write a jolt transform spec to iterate through a loop?

Tags: json, jolt

I have the following

Input JSON :

```json
{
  "a": [
    [
      "a1"
    ],
    [
      "a2"
    ]
  ],
  "b": [
    [
      "b1",
      "b2"
    ],
    [
      "b3",
      "b4"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to use jolt transform to output it like this:

Output JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1"
  },
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b2"
  },
  {
    "a": "a2",
    "b": "b3"
  },
  {
    "a": "a2",
    "b": "b4"
  }
]
```

I use combination of shift and cardinality but can't seem to get it to iterate through correctly:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&].&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

What do I need to change to that jolt transform spec to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can walk by the indexes of the array "b" while picking values from the array "a" as well such as

```json
[
  {
    // partition by indexes of array "a"&"b" while strolling through the array "b"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "b": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,a)": {
            "*": "&.&1.a"
          },
          "*": "&1.&.&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of square brackets wrapping up the values of the attributes "a"
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "a": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // order the attributes by the key names
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Barbaros. What if I have another set of array c, how would I stroll through both array b and array c? So, something like this:

Input:
{
  "a": [
    [
      "a1"
    ],
    [
      "a2"
    ]
  ],
  "b": [
    [
      "b1",
      "b2"
    ],
    [
      "b3",
      "b4"
    ]
  ],
    "c": [
    [
      "c1"
    ],
    [
      "c2"
    ]
  ]
}

Output:
[
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1",
    "c": "c1"
  },
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b2"
  },
  {
    "a": "a2",
    "b": "b3",
    "c": "c2"
  },
  {
    "a": "a2",
    "b": "b4"
  }
]

Comment: I converted this to a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645393/how-do-i-write-a-jolt-transform-spec-to-iterate-through-a-loop-with-multiple-arr