# How do I write a jolt transform spec to iterate through a loop with multiple arrays?

Tags: json, jolt

I have the following

Input JSON :

```json
{
  "a": [
    [
      "a1"
    ],
    [
      "a2"
    ]
  ],
  "b": [
    [
      "b1",
      "b2"
    ],
    [
      "b3",
      "b4"
    ]
  ],
  "c": [
    [
      "c1"
    ],
    [
      "c2"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to use jolt transform to output it like this:

Output JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1",
    "c": "c1"
  },
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b2"
  },
  {
    "a": "a2",
    "b": "b3",
    "c": "c2"
  },
  {
    "a": "a2",
    "b": "b4"
  }
]
```

What's the best way to stroll through the shift operations? I tried multiple shift operations between the 3 arrays but could not get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following specs with **`@(2,a)`** vs. **`@(2,c[&])`** identifiers set as the object labels in order to get the desired output such as

```json
[
  {
    // partition by indexes of array "a"&"b" while strolling through the array "b"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "b": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,a)": {
            "*": "&.&1.a"
          },
          "@(2,c[&])": {
            "*": "&1.&.c"
          },
          "*": "&1.&.&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of square brackets wrapping up the values of the attributes "a"
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "a": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // order the attributes by the key names
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks again Barbaros...greatly appreciate you taking the time to help me out. My biggest confusion with jolt has always been keeping track of the various levels in the json structure to retrieve the data that you need.